# sudo hangs after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: sudo, 20.04

I am experiencing a weird issue after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 over the weekend. Almost every time I execute a sudo command on the terminal it takes upwards of 2 minutes to complete, sometimes as long as 5 minutes.

I have checked that my hostname matches the name in /etc/hosts. I ran `strace sudo ls` to see if I could spot anything weird and if I read the output correctly there is a huge delay polling file descriptor 7:

```
15:17:56 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 300000) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
15:19:26 read(7, "", 16)                = 0
15:19:26 close(7)                       = 0
15:19:26 close(8)                       = 0
15:19:26 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
15:19:26 fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6406312, ...}) = 0
15:19:26 fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6406312, ...}) = 0
15:19:26 getpid()                       = 57431
15:19:26 socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0) = 7
15:19:26 fcntl(7, F_GETFL)              = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
15:19:26 fcntl(7, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
15:19:26 fcntl(7, F_GETFD)              = 0
15:19:26 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)  = 0
15:19:26 connect(7, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/lib/sss/pipes/nss"}, 110) = 0
15:19:26 fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
15:19:26 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 300000) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLOUT}])
15:19:26 sendto(7, "\24\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 16
15:19:26 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 300000) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLOUT}])
15:19:26 sendto(7, "\1\0\0\0", 4, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 4
15:19:26 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 300000) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
15:19:26 read(7, "\24\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 16
15:19:26 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 300000) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
15:19:26 read(7, "\1\0\0\0", 4)         = 4
15:19:26 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 300000) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLOUT}])
15:19:26 sendto(7, "\24\0\0\0\"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 16
15:19:26 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 300000) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLOUT}])
15:19:26 sendto(7, "\222{\225F", 4, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 4
15:19:26 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 300000) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
15:20:56 read(7, "", 16)                = 0
15:20:56 close(7)
```

I ran `ls -la /proc/$PID/fd` and I can see that fd 7 is a socket:

```
lrwx------ 1 root root   64 Apr 28 15:13 7 -> 'socket:[1208329]'
```

Does anybody know what could be causing this massive delay? or what that socket is used for?

I am also experiencing an issue where my login from the lock screen takes > 3 minutes and I suspect this could be related.

Comment: Does `lsof -U` shed any light on what the socket is?

Comment: @steeldriver It shows: `sudo      64053            root    7u  unix 0xffff8f9c7156c400      0t0 1411071 type=STREAM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what is causing sudo to get stuck this morning.

I noticed in the strace output a few lines before the first `POLLIN` there is a call to open and read `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`.

```
14:53:52 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/sssd/sssd.conf", O_RDONLY) = 4
14:53:52 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=696, ...}) = 0
14:53:52 read(4, "[sssd]\nservices = nss, pam\nconfi"..., 4096) = 696
14:53:52 read(4, "", 4096)              = 0
14:53:52 close(4)                       = 0
14:53:52 getpid()                       = 48863
14:53:52 fstat(-1, 0x7ffcd69d5850)      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
```

I couldn't remember what SSSD was so I started digging and I saw that the SSSD service was in a bad state. I have not figured out exactly what is going on but it seems that the `config.ldb` file is corrupt or there is a bug reading from it (I found some info [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1743531))

This would also explain why my login hangs for > 3 minutes since it is probably trying to use SSSD as well.

Since I am not really using SSSD right now the solution was to simply uninstall it.

I hope this can help somebody else. I am still confused as to why a failure in SSSD would cause sudo to hang, I would assume it should be able to carry on and ignore the result of that service but maybe there is some requirement or interaction I don't understand.